How much of an impact do downstream MLCCs have on buck converter phase margin, and how do we mitigate those impacts?
I'm designing a board with a LMR14030-Q1 buck converter which takes 24V in and produces 5.25V out, which then feeds three LD39200 LDOs.
The buck schematic looks like this:

I used TI's WEBENCH tool to generate the above schematic. General design details:

24V nominal input
5.25V nominal output at 1.75Apk, expected load more like 800mA.
Cin is X7R 50V, derates to 2.6uF
Cout is 3x 33uF 45mΩ alupoly
Cff is a 150pF C0G 0603 (CL10C151JB8NNNC)
1.48MHz switching frequency with ±6% center spread
Not pictured: pi filter on the high-side (10uF MLCC + 330nH + 15uF 150mΩ alupoly)
Board uses a 4L SGGS board stackup

I'm generally designing this to meet CISPR25 Class 5 on conducted emissions, but this is only as a good practice measure and not because the board is going through EMC. Probably irrelevant to this question anyway.
The LMR14030-Q1 requires a minimum phase margin of 35°. As designed, WEBENCH reports 99° and all is well. However, I noted that when I switched the alupoly caps out for an equivalent capacitance of MLCCs, the phase margin drops to about 36°, moving it concerningly close to the limit.
I have three LD39200 LDOs on the buck converter's output rail. These LDOs recommend 10uF on the input and output. It seems to me that I need to pay close attention to these input capacitors, since they are directly on the output rail of the buck converter. Since the output rail polygon's parasitics are likely to be negligible (single digit μΩ and nH at most) between the buck's output and the LDO's inputs, it's essentially like putting the MLCCs in parallel with Cout. As I understand it, the effective ESR of the output capacitance is a major contributor to the phase margin, so placing MLCCs in parallel with the alupoly caps is probably going to produce even worse results. This seems to imply that a bunch of 10uF MLCCs would cause the phase margin to be lessened significantly, potentially violating the minimum phase margin requirement.
This situation hadn't really occurred to me before, and I don't think I've ever seen it mentioned in a buck converter appnote either. It also seems like decoupling capacitors would have a similar effect. Given that class 2 MLCC density has climbed significantly in the past decade, and the old "sprinkle 100nF everywhere" and "big/little" decoupling practices make less sense due to modern MLCCs being extremely low impedance, there's a growing trend to use larger (1-10uF) decoupling capacitors on devices that aren't heavily cost-optimised. It seems, to me at least, that this would have a negative impact on upstream switching converter phase margin.
What's the deal here? Is there some reason that the impact of downstream MLCCs (for LDO input caps or general decoupling) is lessened compared to what I see in WEBENCH's phase margin estimations when equivalent MLCCs replace the alupoly caps? Or is this a very real problem? If the latter is the case, are there good methods of mitigating it?

When you say you tried an alternate capacitor and observed a change in phase margin, did you do that in real life or in a simulator? When you add your downstream MLCC's, be sure to consider the trace inductance between the regulator circuit and the MLCC.

@ThePhoton In simulation, and I do generally add parasitics to my models, but in this case I'm surprised that a few nH (on the same order of magnitude as the caps themselves, in the case of the electrolytics) would have a significant effect on phase margin. After all, the output inductor is several orders of magnitude higher inductance.

I don't expect the trace inductance to affect the aluminum part (which is also very close to the regulator) much. But for those MLCC's that are "far away" and also have very small ESL, it's likely to be important.

@ThePhoton So are you saying that it's the ratio between the loop inductances that matters for the impact on phase margin, or that a few nH of series inductance in the power path is sufficient to offset the low package inductance of the MLCCs enough to not shift phase margin by much? (EDIT: Your comment on your answer resolved this for me - it's the trace inductances that offset the low package inductance of the MLCCs.)


reason that the impact of downstream MLCCs (for LDO input caps or general decoupling) is lessened compared to what I see in WEBENCH's phase margin estimations when equivalent MLCCs replace the alupoly caps?

Yes, if the downstream MLCC's are separated from the regulator circuit by a few cm, the path inductance will to some degree isolate them from the regulator feedback network and reduce their impact on the regulator's phase margin.

If the latter is the case, are there good methods of mitigating it?

You can add small resistors (0.5 ohm or less) in series with your MLCC's or just use narrow traces or small vias to add series resistance and inductance.

It also seems like decoupling capacitors would have a similar effect. Given that class 2 MLCC density has climbed significantly in the past decade, and the old "sprinkle 100nF everywhere" and "big/little" decoupling practices make less sense due to modern MLCCs being extremely low impedance,

Even a decade ago the interconnect (trace/wire/path) inductance was likely to limit the MLCC's equivalent resonant frequency more than the internal ESL.

there's a growing trend to use larger (1-10uF) decoupling capacitors on devices that aren't heavily cost-optimised. It seems, to me at least, that this would have a negative impact on upstream switching converter phase margin.

It's a reasonable concern. It would be worth doing a study using a power integrity simulator to determine the equivalent Y(f) of the power distribution network and decoupling capacitors, and use that to model the load on the regulator and check the phase margin. This is the kind of thing that could become a presentation at DesignCon or a similar conference.

Are single-digit nH of inductance really sufficient to separate the MLCCs? A typical MLCC has a few hundred pH of inductance, and an electrolytic cap typically pushes 1nH of inductance, so it seems odd to me that the inductance of few tens of millimeters of power polygon would have a significant effect at isolating the effect of the MLCC.

Trace inductance is measured in nH per mm. It'll be slightly lower for a plane, but still the same order of magnitude. So it's going to be a bigger contributor to the behavior than the part's internal ESL. (I'm talking about MLCC's, which I thought were the focus of your question)

Ah, that's higher than I remembered it being. That makes more intuitive sense to me, then - the phase margin gets reduced by the very low loop inductance with MLCCs, due to their package inductances being so tiny, but once you move to electrolytics or move the MLCCs further away the parasitic trace inductances are sufficient to negate that phase margin reduction. Thanks.

1 nH/mm is the number I've used for bondwire inductance. Of course that's about the skinniest wire you're going to see, and it's placed fairly close to its return path, so this might be more an upper limit on trace inductance per unit length. But things aren't going to be better by a factor of 10 no matter how wide you make a trace or power plane.

Again it would probably be interesting to do simulate a representative design in Hyperlinx PI, or Ansys SIWave, or a Momentum simulator to get some real numbers.

Field solving this is bit beyond my capabilities (and budget! those Ansys licenses don't come cheap) but I've done MLCC package inductance characterisation before so I can probably do something similar with the PCB traces.
